# Why recurrence relations arise in analyzing the running times of recursive algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Why recurrence relations arise in analyzing the running times of recursive algorithms? 
I could not understand this, can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't "arise," really.  The recurrence relation *describes* the behavior of each step of the recursive algorithm's solution, more or less the complexity of the recursive function without including the overhead of the recursive call.

For example, a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) makes a comparison and then divides the input array in half, so the recurrence relation looks like `T(n) = T(n/2) + ϴ(1)`, where ϴ(1) ("big-theta") refers to a fixed-time operation:  The comparison, in this case.